# Read/write DNS settings for macOS using Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, dns

Is there any way to read/write DNS settings on macOS using Swift? The Swift documentation shows the [DNS Proxy Provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/dns_proxy_provider) for iOS, but I don't see any similar extensions that support macOS.

Comment: That last line of the overview. "DNS proxy providers are only supported on supervised iOS devices."

Comment: @MwcsMac I'm aware of that, I want to know if there are any other alternatives for macOS.